# Deriving a dataframe by combining two other data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and trying my hands on certain problems. I have a situation where I have 2 dataframe which I want to combine to achieve my desired dataframe.

I have tried .merge and .join, both of which was not able to get my desired outbcome.

let us suppose I have the below scenario:

```
lt = list(['a','b','c','d','a','b','a','b'])
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = lt)

data = [[10,11,12,12], [15,14,12,10]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['a','b','c','d'])
```

I want df and df1 to be combined and get desired dataframe as df2 as:

```
    a   b   c   d   a   b   a   b
0   10  11  12  12  10  11  10  11
1   15  14  12  10  15  14  15  14
```

Comment: did you check `df2 = df1[df.columns]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind the order of the columns changing, this is just a right join. The only caveat is that those are performed on rows rather than columns, so you need to transpose first:

```py
In [44]: df.T.join(df1.T, how='right').T
Out[44]:
    a   a   a   b   b   b   c   d
0  10  10  10  11  11  11  12  12
1  15  15  15  14  14  14  12  10
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to use the columns of `df` and select the corresponding columns in `df1`, like so:

```py
lt = list(['a','b','c','d','a','b','a','b'])
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = lt)

data = [[10,11,12,12], [15,14,12,10]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['a','b','c','d']) 

df2 = df1[df.columns]
print(df2)
```

prints:

```
    a   b   c   d   a   b   a   b
0  10  11  12  12  10  11  10  11
1  15  14  12  10  15  14  15  14
```

Comment: Hi tschmelz, yes...this is working for the above sample. But not for my original dataframe. It is throwing error: "xxxx,yyyy not in index"

Answer (score 0):

Use [`concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)

```py
pd.concat([df, df1], axis=0, join='inner', sort=False)
    a   b   c   d   a   b   a   b
0  10  11  12  12  10  11  10  11
1  15  14  12  10  15  14  15  14
```

Comment: Tried .cocat, but getting error " Plan shapes are not aligned"...

Comment: are you using axis=0 and join='inner'?